# In MDX, how can the conditions for calculated member be applied to both the individual lines and the total?

Tags: mdx

I want to create a calculated member that filter some lines. The total must also respect the filter.

I have defined the following calculated member in a cube:

`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SemiFilteredAmount] AS
IIF(
([Dim1].[AttrHier1].CurrentMember IS [Dim1].[AttrHier1].&[PK_A]) OR
([Dim1].[AttrHier1].CurrentMember IS [Dim1].[AttrHier1].&[PK_B]),

([Measures].[Amount], [Dim2].[AttrHier2].&[PK_C]),

[Measures].[Amount]
),
FORMAT_STRING = "#,0.00", VISIBLE = 1;`

In my report, I have this member on COLUMNS and [Dim1].[AttrHier1].All.Children on ROWS.

On the row level, the measure works as expected, but the total does not take the logic into account. I understand why this is so, but what must I do so that the total takes the logic into account, i.e. so that the total is the total of the *semi-filtered* lines? Can I use the SCOPE statement?